# How to dynamically copy selected ListItems from a ListBox to a DropDownList AND have it display correctly in a Webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My problem is the codebehind looks like it works and according to the debugger, it does (no errors or exceptions). Unfortunately it does not actually work on my asp.net webforms webpage, the DropdownList does not actually populate with the selected items of the ListBox. This really should have been simple, but apparently not.

My research said that the Listboxes and DropDownList should be inside of UpdatePanels, and children as triggers needed to be set to true, and with the help of the ScriptManager it would intercept postback requests and do only partial page updates. Nevertheless when that did not work I tried calling the updatepanels.update() method directly and this did not work either.

Here is my C# code.

```
  protected void GroupList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updategroupEntry();
    }

    protected void updategroupEntry() 
    {
        EnterAGroup.Items.Clear();
        foreach (ListItem li in GroupList.Items)
        {
            if (li.Selected)
            {
                EnterAGroup.Items.Add(li);
            }
        }
        OptionsUpdater.Update();
        OverallUpdater.Update();
    }
```

In my code I use nested update panels, the overall/surrounding one is shown here, I have also included the closing tags for the one in my second DropdownList. Here is the first code segment.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="OverallUpdater" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
       <ContentTemplate>

 //irrelevant code omitted

                <asp:Listbox AutoPostback="True" ID="GroupList" runat="server" Width="166px"  SelectionMode="Multiple" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GroupList_SelectedIndexChanged" DataSourceID="GroupSource" DataTextField="GroupName" DataValueField="GroupID">
                </asp:Listbox>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="GroupSource" runat="server"
                     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ACESConnectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [GroupName], [GroupID] FROM [PrimaryGroup] ORDER BY [GroupName]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

 //more code omitted

              <%--End of Options Panel --%>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ContentTemplate>
              </asp:UpdatePanel> 

        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="viewapps" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UpdateButton" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FilterButton" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In my aspx page I have this code around my DropDownList.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="OptionsUpdater" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server"  ChildrenAsTriggers="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled"> 
       <ContentTemplate>

  //other code omitted for brevity.

          <asp:TableCell>
             <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="EnterAGroup" BackColor="PaleVioletRed" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
          </asp:TableCell>

 //other code omitted for brevity.

    </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

So the codebehind says its works, but it just isn't updating on the webpage. How do I get it to work correctly?

I will be glad to give more code upon request.
Also, if you need to test the code, I recommend substituting your own SqlDataSource with 2 columns from some table.

**Update**
I have tried Cherian M Paul's idea and its producing strange results where it only half-way works when I select all items from the group but not only a few.

Here is it halfway working when all groups are selected.

[image: Half way working when ALL groups are selected]

Here is an image of it not working when only some are selected.
[image: Not working when only some are selected]

**Update**

After further investigation there is a point where there is a disconnect and clicks on the webpage no longer reach the codebehind.

I have a video of this disconnection. basically, at the end no amount of clicks will trigger the events in my codebehind.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B12ZVcp_VQ_xR3c0cU1LaXd5Vkk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I believe that, you need to add the trigger for the second UpdatePanel with ID as `OptionsUpdater`. Similar to the way you did for the first one.

`<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GroupList" 
EventName="GroupList_SelectedIndexChanged" />`

Please try updating the html. Also there is no partial update, while using update panel also, asp.net actually does all the work , but only a part of the page is updated and user feels like it is doing some thing on back end.

Can I suggest you to achieve these kind of tasks using jQuery.

Comment: I will try that. I can easily use jQuery to update an html version of a dropdownlist. But I don't really know how to write a webservice method to receive the ajax call from jQuery, also its annoying that the script manager unbinds my dom events I set up in jQuery. If you have a link to a good tutorial on how to write a webservice method and jquery ajax call to it that would be good..

Comment: Okay, I am done with doing this the hard way, I am going to try the jQuery way.

Comment: I will try this tutorial. http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett just try with jquery . Webmethod is a good option also you can try with jquery post/jquery ajax

Comment: I can use jQuery to populate my <select>, but I can't use ONLY jQuery.   I need to communicate with my codebehind. There are database operations being done based on the results of what is selected in the <select> in other C# methods in my codebehind. I need to asynchronously send these values back to the application server.

Comment: I think you can achieve all by jquery ajax

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (ListItem li in GroupList.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected)
    {
        EnterAGroup.Items.Add(li);
    }
}
```

The above code will not work because dropdownlist can't have multiple selected items. Please change the code as below, then it will work.

```
foreach (ListItem li in GroupList.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected)
    {
        EnterAGroup.Items.Add(new ListItem(li.Text, li.Value));
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives me strange results. It only appears to work when all items are selected. I will post a picture to explain.

Comment: I copied your code from above and put it into a seperate webpage and it worked. I just removed the below triggers.        

<Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="viewapps" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UpdateButton" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FilterButton" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>

Comment: Interesting, is it possible to have too many items overloading an update panel?

Comment: No. I don't think so. Can you remove the triggers and try to run it?

Comment: Oh weird, when I click on something else when I it starts working when the triggers are disabled.  But then it got disconnected from the codebehind, no more clicks are triggering any line by line in my codebehind. Unfortunately I actually need those triggers for other stuff.

Comment: Make sure you add my change to your code and then try to debug. There is something else going on. The code worked for me only after I changed to EnterAGroup.Items.Add(new ListItem(li.Text, li.Value));
Add the triggers back.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35619/discussion-between-cherian-m-paul-and-alexander-ryan-baggett)

Comment: Certainly I am there.