# How to dynamically generate jQuery to populate options for a <select> using C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

My question pretty much says it all. I have tried a lot. My code compiles, but does not work (despite appearances). Also, there aren't any Javascript errors in the error console, so I am kind of stumped as to what I am doing wrong.

**Edit: To make it clearer for people I will emphasize the problem**

### The problem is that the select box is not getting any options/isn't being populated.

Here is the C# in the codebehind.

```
  protected void GroupList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  updategroupEntry(); }

    protected void updategroupEntry() 
    {
        //this is used to populate the second group list.
        string JSCMD = "";
        JSCMD += "$('#grouplist2').empty();";
        foreach (ListItem li in GroupList.Items)
        {
            if (li.Selected)
            {
                JSCMD += "$('#groupList2').append('<option value=" + li.Value + ">" + li.Text + "</option>');";
            }
        }
        JSCMD += "alert('I send javascript correctly');";
        sendGenericscript(JSCMD);

    }

//sends scripts to the webpage
   private void sendGenericscript(string script) 
    {
        const string someScript = "alertMe";
        //send the built script to the website.
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), someScript, script, true);
    }
```

This whole thing is called by SelectedIndexChanged event over here in my aspx.

```
    <asp:Listbox AutoPostback="True" ID="GroupList" runat="server" Width="166px" 
                     SelectionMode="Multiple" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GroupList_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                    DataSourceID="GroupSource" DataTextField="GroupName" DataValueField="GroupID">
                </asp:Listbox>
```

And the affected guy is here.

```
  <select style="width:150px;" id="grouplist2">

  </select>
```

The test/debug alertbox does appear so I know my script is reaching the page.

Here is my page getting jquery from the masterpage.

```
             <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                <Scripts>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jqueryui.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/menubar.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/AutoSuggestBox.js" />
                </Scripts>
            </asp:ScriptManager>
```

And here is the reference to the stuff in my page.

```
 <%@ Page Title="MassUpdate" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Update.aspx.cs" Inherits="AdminSite.Update" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="headcontent" runat="server">
 </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server" >      
        <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server"  >
            <Scripts>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/MassUpdate.js" />  
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

Comment: Where is your javascript code?

Comment: Its being dynamically generated. Look more closely at updategroupEntry()

Comment: Can I ask why you're building a client-side script on the server, instead of just populating the `<select>` directly?

Comment: Sure. This kind of relates to a previous post of mine. Basically, I have a listbox(asp.net) that is populated with the contents of a database call. What I need is my select to have only the selected values from that in it. The easy to way to do it for me is to refer to the Listbox in the codebehind, rather than trying to bind an event to the dom to copy only the selected ones over to the new <select>. I think its possible to do it all in javascript and cut out server side completely yes, But I am stronger in my C# than my javascript and jquery.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett Hope you had the required javascript references in the html for Jquery

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to show that code. I am getting jquery from a script reference in my master page. I didn't think to include it in the post but I certainly can.

Comment: Someone seems to think, I haven't done enough research or put forth enough effort.  Personally though, I believe the large amounts of code samples would suggest that I am in fact trying.  Basically, I am 99% of the way there, I really just want to know what I am doing incorrectly so I can fix it. I am not asking for people to redo the whole thing for me.

Comment: is this an issue with dynamic creation of the html?

Comment: I don't believe that is the case. I believe the problem is that the javascript/jquery that is being dynamically generated is not having the intended effect of adding options to a <select>.

Comment: I have edited my title to make the problem more clear.

Comment: Try to put your Javascript bits within the jQuery page loaded event: `$(function() { your code here });`

Answer (score 0):

I'm still unsure about why you don't just populate the select box with server-side code, but you might need to defer your script execution until the DOM has been loaded. Can you try this:

```
string JSCMD = "$(function(){";
    JSCMD += "$('#grouplist2').empty();";
    foreach (ListItem li in GroupList.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected)
        {
            JSCMD += "$('#groupList2').append('<option value=" + li.Value + ">" + li.Text + "</option>');});";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, the reason I didn't do it all server side is because I tried already. =(  . I have a whole other stackoverflow post for that issue =( . You can view it here.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278169/how-to-dynamically-copy-selected-listitems-from-a-listbox-to-a-dropdownlist-and